# HIS Multiview II USB Video Adapter not compatible with Intel(R) 82945G Express Chipset Family on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb

I attempted to install a `HIS Multiview II USB Video Adapter` on Windows 7 64-bit.  When I tried to install the driver, from the website and from the dvd that came with it, I got an error stating that it was incompatible with the `Intel(R) 82945G Express Chipset Family`.  Is there anything that can be done about this, short of buying a new video card?

The software that gives the error when installing is called `DisplayLink Manager Version 7.5.54018.0`

Also when I plug in the `HIS Multiview II` into the `Dell Optiplex GX520` I get a message that `this device can perform faster`; the system is a `Pentium 4`, so the problem could also be that this machine is pre-USB 2.0.

Comment: You have a two fold problem your not using USB 2.0 nor is your hardware compatible with the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope that wasn't the issue.  The issue was the VGA 2 DVI adapter plug I was using.  I must have picked up a different one in the shuffle; anyway the one had four prongs on it and the other one did not.

[image: Adapter with four prongs on the left and separate adapter no prongs on the right.]

I also noticed that the two arrows seem to be pointing in alternate directions, I'm not sure if that's some sort of standard indicator or what.

[image: Adapter with four prongs on the left with the arrow on top pointing to the right, and a separate adapter on the right with no prongs and an arrow pointing to the left.]

The adapter with `four prongs` is a `DL-DVI-I` plug, and the adapter with no prongs is a `DL-DVI-D` plug.

The working adapter had a `DL-DVI-I` plug and when it plugged into the `HIS Multiview II USB Video Adapter` which had a `DVI-I` connector on it.